# Do...While Loop keeps printing non stop

Tags: c

I have this piece of code that asks a user for age, and if the input is not a number, it will go back and ask the user again. But for some reason, it simply prints the first printf statement non stop. What am I doing wrong?

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age == 0)
    {
    printf("Please make sure to only enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    }
} while (isdigit(age) == 0);
```

Comment: be aware `isdigit()` test for a single `character`. You're testing an `integer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isdigit()` will always return `0`, except for some special values, try `52`.

The `isdigit()` function is meant for an ascii value, if the ascii value corresponds to that of a digit, then it returns `1`, else it will return `0`, so for most of the numbers you input, the result will be `0`.

If you need to stop the loop whenever a non-numeric character is entered, then you need to check the `scanf()` return value, that's what it is for.

There will be problems, if you try to ask the user again for a value, because if a `'\n'` character is left in the input buffer, `scanf()` will ignore it, and continue reading, leading to an infinite loop, so this should work for you

```
printf("Please enter your age: ");
while ((scanf("%d", &age) != 1) || (age == 0))
{
    int chr;
    do {
        chr = getchar();
    } while ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
    printf("Please make sure to only enter an integer: ");
}
```

Comment: The original code works nicely if you're old enough -- between 48 and 57, to be precise.  You youngsters just have to keep entering your age until you're old enough, that's all.  :D